# Struts 2 ModelDriven for different request parameter name and bean property name

Tags: struts2, struts-config, model-driven

Is it possible to assign the value to the bean property by implementing ModelDriven interface but having different name in request and bean

for eg Ajax request
DemoStruts.Action?param_a=649

the value of param_a parameter must set to the property paramAR in the bean. For doing this is there any xml configuration or annotation to specify this mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal mechanism is the [alias interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/alias-interceptor.html), although I haven't used it for deep aliasing.

There are some pretty hideous games you can play with this technique. I've never been entirely sure if it's a good idea or not, though; another option is to just map parameters manually in the action itself. This is often easier to understand.